# Multi-agent model: To create unique breeds for each agent or to use agentset?

Tags: netlogo

As I need 4 players to have their own variables (which all players happens to have too), i am creating separate breed and declaring variables as follows:

```
breed [player1]
breed [player2]
breed [player3]
breed [player4]

player1-own [mood_player1]
player2-own [mood_player2]
player3-own [mood_player3]
player4-own [mood_player4]
```

I then treat each player as unique, and write codes for each.

Am I supposed to use agentset instead? If so, how can I still achieve the same ease in identification for each player's mood? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd normally suggest:

```
breed [players player]
players-own [mood]
```

Then you can make 4 players with:

```
create-players 4
```

Then you can refer to them by who number as `player 0`, `player 1`, `player 2`, and `player 3`. This assumes they are the first four turtles created.

If you don't like that the who numbers start at 0, or if the players aren't the first turtles created, then another option would be:

```
breed [players player]
players-own [mood]
globals [player1 player2 player3 player4]

create-players 1 [ set player1 self ]
create-players 1 [ set player2 self ]
create-players 1 [ set player3 self ]
create-players 1 [ set player4 self ]
```

which bypasses any dependence on who numbering.